# Google URL Testing Tools API - Simple Web App Setup

Tags: javascript, google-api-webmasters

I'd like to create my first web app using the Google URL Testing Tools API but haven't a clue where to start (https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/).  I find the documentation very confusing and am struggling to find any real examples online. I have extensive HTML and CSS experience and also know my way around JavaScript and JSON. Note also that I have an API key.

I'd like to create a simple HTML page that returns 5 submitted chosen URL's to see whether they are mobile friendly or not. Sounds simple right - not for me.

Hope someone can help out as feeling a little lost. Any pointers from where to start would help massively.

Lee

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just be looking in the wrong place. They have a couple of examples, including one in JavaScript, here:

https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api/v1/samples

If that doesn't work, you can use a php or other server-side script to wrap the shell command:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{url: "YOUR_URL"}' 'https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/v1/urlTestingTools/mobileFriendlyTest:run?key=YOUR_API_KEY'
```

found here: https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api/v1/getting-started#curl-usage